# GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD : What do you mean by Idempotent

Tags: http

I was listening a video on youtube on REST API, below is the link:

[REST API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdSrT4yjS1g)

**It is said that GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD are idempotent operations i.e. you can invoke them multiple times and get the same state on the server.**

Would anybody please elaborate this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just what it says

No matter how many times that `Resource` is requested with the exact same URL, the state on the server will never change as a side effect because of the request.

> idempotent:
>
> Denoting an element of a set that is unchanged in value when
>   multiplied or otherwise operated on by itself

### The point is multiple requests that are exactly the same:

So if you request an image from a server 1000 times with the **same URL**, nothing on the server is changed.

> If you call `DELETE` multiple times on the same resource, they state
>   on the server doesn't change. This removes the resource, and nothing
>   else, no side effect. And if the resource is not there, good that is
>   what we wanted and nothing else should be affected on the server.

Those `Verbs` should never have side effects.

Doing a `GET` should not cause side effects to alter the state of the server no matter how many times this exact URL is requested.

### It is about repeated subsequent calls

> Example:
>
> Calling `GET` on a resource should NOT modify a database record, or
>   cause any changes. If it does it isn't following the rules.

If you call `HEAD` on a resource 1000 times in a row, the state on the server should not change. It might return different data because some removed the resource separately, but **repeated calls should never do anything different on the server.**

### What is NOT idempotent

Example:

> Calling `GET` multiple times causes a counter on tracking that
>   resource to increment every time you make the request with the exact
>   same URL. This is **not** idempotent. There is a side effect and the
>   state of the server is changing because of the request.

Comment: How can the state be the same, I can modify the resource, So in that case state will be changes. Suppose I will say http://localhost:8080/employees/1 it will give me information about employee no. 1. But i can modify the employee attributes and next time when i call this, then i will get a different state. I am confused.

Comment: The point is about multiple requests, they don't cause compounding side effects.

Comment: I am not modifying the employee in the get request. First of all, I request the employee data using GET request. Then I modify it using POST request and then I again GET it using GET request. So I will get a modified data this time.

Comment: the point is not that they don't do anything. The point is that they don't do anything after the first invocation

Comment: @SAM it is perfectly fine. It is the POST that changes the state of the resource. GETs only retrieve that state but don't change it themselves

Comment: Would you please explain this by taking an example?

Comment: @SAM deleting the same thing twice is the same as deleting once. "I've crushed my car, then I've crushed my car" has the same effects as "I've crushed my car", thus crushing your car is an idempotent action.

Comment: `POST` can be idempotent as well, if it you call with the **exact same data, the state on the server should not change on *subsequent* calls**.

Comment: This mean its our implementation that makes something idempotent or non-idempotent. It is recommended by HTTP specification to use these methods as idempotent. Am I right?

Comment: As a simple example, consider: localhost:8080/employees/1?increasePayBy=100. If your code increases the employees pay by 100 every time the GET request is performed, that means it isn't idempotent - because something on the server is being changed every time that request gets sent, for whatever reason. An idempotent action would be more like ?setNewPayRate=500. There is a different dictum about not allowing such actions through GET and only using POST, but that has nothing to do with the definition of idempotent

Comment: The point about counters is incorrect; what's important are the side effects intended by who makes the request. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-24.html#idempotent.methods

Answer (score 0):

**Idempotent** means no matter how many times you invoke that method (e.g. `GET`), you won't introduce [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). For example when you issue a `GET` request to a URL (navigating to `http://www.google.com` in a browser), you theoretically won't change the state of the web server no matter how many `GET` requests you issued to the server.

As a real world example, you shouldn't allow some database `DELETE`/`INSERT` operations be accessible via an HTTP `GET`. There are numerous accidents for the Google Crawler to accidentally deleted entities from databases while crawling (i.e. `GET`ting) websites.

Comment: A language barrier may be in play here, but I think you're trying to define "nilpotent", not "idempotent".

Comment: Jan: "safe" in HTTP speak.